# ¿Cómo convertir decimales a horas y sumarlas en SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una tabla Horas en la cual los registros se ingresan de forma decimal.
Lo que necesito es que al sumar las horas, NO se sumen como decimales. Por ejemplo: si tengo 1.68 y 0.30, que el total sea 2.38 horas y no 1.98.

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
    Select  Horas.HRS_Horas As Horas,
            Usuarios.USU_NombreInterno As Nombre
    From    PRY_Horas Horas With(NoLock)
            Join PRY_Semanas Semanas With(NoLock) 
                On Semanas.SEM_Id = Horas.SEM_Id
            Join PRY_Actividades Actividades With(NoLock) 
                On Actividades.ACT_Id = Horas.ACT_Id
            Join PRY_Estatus Estatus With(NoLock) 
                On Estatus.EST_Id = Horas.EST_Id
            Join ACC_Usuarios Usuarios With(NoLock) 
                On Usuarios.USU_Usuario = Horas.HRS_Usuario
    Where   Horas.SEM_Id = 207
            And Actividades.ACT_Activo = 1
            And Horas.HRS_Usuario = 'felipe.velazquez'
```

Lo cuál me arroja los siguientes registros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al hacer la suma con la consulta:

```
    Select  SUM(Horas.HRS_Horas) As Total
    From    PRY_Horas Horas With(NoLock)
            Join PRY_Semanas Semanas With(NoLock) 
                On Semanas.SEM_Id = Horas.SEM_Id
            Join PRY_Actividades Actividades With(NoLock) 
                On Actividades.ACT_Id = Horas.ACT_Id
            Join PRY_Estatus Estatus With(NoLock) 
                On Estatus.EST_Id = Horas.EST_Id
            Join ACC_Usuarios Usuarios With(NoLock) 
                On Usuarios.USU_Usuario = Horas.HRS_Usuario
    Where   Horas.SEM_Id = 207
            And Actividades.ACT_Activo = 1
            And Horas.HRS_Usuario = 'felipe.velazquez'
```

Me arroja 6.03, y yo espero que me de 7.23 horas.

Espero y me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Cómo tienes 1.68 horas refiriendose a una hora con 68 minutos y por qué sería diferente a tener una hora con 98 minutos? Sería importante que valides bien los valores y uses los tipos de datos correctos como sería una columna tipo `time` o dos columnas  `int` para representar por separado horas y minutos.

Comment: La idea es convertir ese 1.68 a 2.08 horas, aunque entiendo tu punto @LuisCazares, lo malo es que por la cantidad de registros que tiene la tabla, creo que no es buena idea cambiar su estructura.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como lo mencioné en los comentarios, el diseño está incorrecto y eso hace que todo se vuelva más complejo. Lo ideal es poder validar los datos y separar las horas de los minutos. Si no se hace desde el diseño de la tabla, se tendrá que hacer cada vez que se consulte.

Separar las horas es sencillo, solo hay que truncar el valor y eso se hace utilizando el tercer parámetro de `ROUND`. Para separar los minutos, tenemos que restar el valor total de los enteros y luego multiplicar por cien para obtener valores enteros y trabajar con ellos.

```
DECLARE @Ejemplo TABLE(
    Total decimal(10,2),
    Nombre varchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO @Ejemplo
VALUES( 2.43, 'Felipe Velazquez'),
       ( 1.68, 'Felipe Velazquez'),
       ( 1.92, 'Felipe Velazquez');
   

SELECT Nombre, 
        --Sumamos los enteros
        SUM( ROUND( Total, 0, 1)) 
        --Sumamos los minutos y extraemos las horas
        + SUM(CAST((Total - ROUND( Total, 0, 1)) * 100 AS int)) / 60 
        --Sumamos los minutos y extraemos el residuo después de extraer las horas
        + (SUM(CAST((Total - ROUND( Total, 0, 1)) * 100 AS int)) % 60) / 100.
FROM @Ejemplo
GROUP BY Nombre;
```

Por último, es importante que estés consciente de que los hints NOLOCK pueden generar información incorrecta, no ayudan a que las consultas sean más rápidas y tampoco previenen que se bloqueen los datos. Si tienen un problema de bloqueo, hay otras formas de combatirlo. Si no lo tienen, solo están agregando problemas al código.

Comment: No tiene nada que ver con el problema, pero si el hint NOLOCK no es eficiente para evitar bloqueo de data o de la tabla en realidad, qué otra forma se puede usar para asegurar que el bloqueo no suceda?

Comment: Es un tema muy amplio, pero en general las soluciones son mediante el diseño de buenos índices, buenas consultas y asignar el nivel de aislamiento adecuado. Puedes leer más acerca de `READ COMMITED SNAPSHOT` y de ahí partir para ver si se ajusta a tus necesidades. En general, los bloqueos no son malos. Tienen su razón de ser y están ahí para proteger la información.